# Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined "Socket + Angular + Node "

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, mean

I created this event in my node server :

```
socket.on('hello' , function (data) {console.log('hello from the other side');})
```

on my chat component i have put :

```
constructor(private authService:AuthService,private router : Router) {
const socket=io('http://localhost:4000');
console.log(socket);}


onSendMessage(){
console.log('yep yep');
console.log(this.socket);
this.socket.emit('hello');
}
```

And on my chat component.html :

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="chat" id="chat">        </div>
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSendMessage()">
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form control" id="message"></textarea>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message"/>
                  </div>
            </form>
      </div>
```

And the result is this :

> Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
>       at ChatComponent.push../src/app/components/chat/chat.component.ts.ChatComponent.onSendMessage

Here is an image of the web console : [image]

PS : whenever i click send message the socket always disconnect and reconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that socket is not a member of your char component you should declare it first as a member of your component to user this.socket , or if it's a service you use directly Inject it in the constructor then it becomes a member of your class and you can use (this.socket)

Comment: i already decleared it : 
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  sender  : any ;
  receiver : any ;
  reference : any ;
  token : any;
  message : any ;
  socket;

Comment: I think in the constructor you need to make it like this : this.socket = io('localhost:4000') then you can use it in the onSendMessage Function

Comment: yeah it worked. 
i have a problem that when i send a message the socket disconnects and then reconnects